# php ternary operator formatting

Tags: php

This works:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : '' ?>"/>
```

This does not:

```
echo('<input type="text" name="foo" value="'.isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : ''.'"/>');
```

Notice: Undefined index: foo in /srv/www/form.php on line 15

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP's operator precedence rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) make it evaluate your second example as follows:

```
echo(
  ('<input type="text" name="foo" value="'.isset($_POST['foo']))
    ? $_POST['foo']
    : (''.'"/>')
);
```

That doesn't make a lot of sense in several ways. And since the result of `isset()` is essentially disregarded, this always ends up just trying to print `$_POST['foo']`. And that results in a notice when it's not set, of course.

Add parentheses around the actual ternary expression. I.e.

```
(isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the expression in the parenthesis:

```
echo('<input type="text" name="foo" value="'. (isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : '') .'"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, parenthesis (as suggested by zerkms) makes code unreadable.

Instead, think something like this:

```
$value = isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : '';
echo '<input type="text" name="foo" value="'. $value .'"/>';
```